# How to remove leading / at each line a text file with sed Linux command

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing

This is my text file and I want to remove every first line:

```
aaaa
bbbb/bbbb
/cccc/cccc
/Dddd/zzzz/wwww
.gggg
.oooo/sssss
/.vvvvv
!@%#/$%
```

How can I remove all first "/" from my text file?

I want the result text file to be like:

```
aaaa
bbbb/bbbb
cccc/cccc
Dddd/zzzz/wwww
.gggg
.oooo/sssss
.vvvvv
!@%#/$%
```

if it's any help, I'm using `sed` command.

Comment: If it is one file, it has exactly one first line, so _every_ doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Also, you should show the script, which with you attempted your solution.

Comment: Sounds like ```google translate``` failed ^^

Comment: revision done ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` can be instructed to replace the first `/` of each line with nothing:

```sh
sed 's_^/__' 'my text file name'
```

Comment: hi lea, It worked but actually didn't remove "/"

Comment: You need the `-i` option flag if your sed has it.